# Извлечь угол поворота и масштаб из матрицы перспективного преобразования

Tags: opencv, матрицы, геометрия

С помощью OpenCV в программе сопоставляются 4 точки одного изображения и 4 точки другого. На выходе получается матрица M 3x3 вида:

```
[a1 b1 dx]   
[a2 b2 dy]   
[p1 p2 1 ]
```

Например:

```
 [ 4.93670886e-01 -8.63584063e-18 -4.93670886e+00]
 [ 3.37282944e-17  1.00000000e+00 -5.00000000e+00]
 [ 8.64828062e-19  6.46413988e-35  1.00000000e+00]
```

Выполняется все это с помощью подобного кода, разве что числа немного другие:

```
img = cv2.imread('sudokusmall.png')
rows,cols,ch = img.shape

pts1 = np.float32([[56,65],[368,52],[28,387],[389,390]])
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[300,0],[0,300],[300,300]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(300,300))

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Output')
plt.show()
```

Необходимо из полученной матрицы М извлечь масштабные коэффициенты по осям x и y и угол поворота

Answer (score 0):

А что такое "угол поворота" и "масштабные коэффициенты" для перспективного (не аффинного!) преобразования? Для этого есть общепринятые соглашения?

Если произвести [QR-разложение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) данной матрицы, то получим в R ортогональную матрицу, а ортогональная матрица описывает некое вращение. Видимо, это вращение нужно соответствующим образом интерпретировать.

Т.н. "масштабные коэффициенты"  участвуют в верхнетреугольной матрице Q